# Android Saving a Bitmap in a Folder -Duplicates-

Tags: android, file, bitmap, save

My problem is whenever I save the bitmap. I saves one in the folder I want(MyFolder) and one in the DCIM/Camera. I don't see any code that makes it save int he DCIM directory?

Here are my codes...

```
    case R.id.menu_save:
        try {

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();
            File myNewFolder = new File(path + "/MyFolder");
            myNewFolder.mkdirs();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file = new File(path, "/MyFolder/HK" + filename + ".jpg");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    filename + "Has been saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Problem to Save the File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        break;
```

Comment: I believe `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName())` is what is reading your image saved through `fout` to your selected path and writing it to the DCIM folder

Comment: this will help to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469234/captured-image-is-not-stored-in-the-specific-folder-in-android

Comment: MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath()‌​, file.getName(), file.getName()) That is right, when I delete that code the problem solved. If you write as an answer I can accept as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As in the thread @Dixit linked, you can specify the file path URI with

```
File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
    "/saved_images");
fileDir.mkdirs();

File file = new File(fileDir, "image.jpg");

Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

This way the camera will save the image to the specified path instead of the DCIM folder.

**EDIT:** You have to create the folder on the sdcard beforehand, maybe that's the problem. Otherwise, this should work.

Comment: It saves the directory I want no problem. But it saves also DCIM folder, but my problem resolved thank you.